# psql command-line variable interpolation leads to syntax error

Tags: postgresql, shell

From the [psql command documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html), the `--variable` command described as making variables available for substitution with `:name` syntax. However,

```
psql --variable=var="'hello'" -c 'select :var'
```

...results in a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: select :var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works correctly if the query text is fed in on stdin in bash:

```
psql --variable=var="'hello'" <<<"select :var"
```

Or by using POSIX sh:

```
psql --variable=var="'hello'" <<<'EOF'
select :var
EOF
```