# psql syntax error at command line with variable interpolation

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I have a scenario like below with Postgres 9.4.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION something(varA text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    ...
    RAISE INFO '%',varA;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DO
$$
declare
    varA text := :cmd_line_arg;
begin
    perform something(varA);
end;
$$
```

All this resides in some file `plpgsql.sql` and is executed like so:

```
psql -v cmd_line_arg='value' -U postgres -d postgres -f plpgsql.sql
```

I receive `syntax error at or near`':'

I have also found errors when using the string concatenation operator `||`.

What am I missing here? Is it something to do with the `DO`?

NOTE: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868167/psql-command-line-variable-interpolation-leads-to-syntax-error) did not help.

Comment: perform can be used outside of functions? i believe it did not work that way so i used th do block

Comment: You're right. I've mistaken it with `PREPARE`. Anyways, try enclosing your `cmd_line_arg` within `' '`.

Comment: unfortunately enclosing within `''` took it as a literal string instead of using the value.

Comment: This may be due to the `DO` block. Could you please try `SELECT 1 FROM something(:'cmd_line_arg') LIMIT 0` instead of your `DO` block? You could also try without `' '`, but I'm thinking this should work too for your pg version

Comment: no this did not work either. I tried `select something(:'cmd_line_arg')` too, which also failed.

Answer (score 0):

#### PL/pgSQL error

PL/pgSQL [`RAISE` allows various syntax variants.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) Yours is not among them. Try instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION something(varA text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   ...
   RAISE INFO '%', varA;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### psql error

The [SQL interpolation feature of psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) does not work *inside* strings. The body of a function or `DO` command happens to be a plain string. You need to concatenate. Like:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   varA text := $$ || :'cmd_line_arg' || $$
BEGIN
   PERFORM something(varA);
END
$$;
```

Also note the added quotes in `:'cmd_line_arg'`.

Comment: I realised that and tried to use the concat operator but then it started throwing syntax error for that. its really weird. and about the raise i have corrected it.

Comment: @KoushikShetty: So does the code I suggest still throw an error? Because it works for me ...

Comment: yes it still is. i'm suspecting it is something else now. even `language` is throwing up. Is it that it is not being detected as plsql? i dont know anymore

Comment: @KoushikShetty. You probably have more errors. plsql is the Oracle language. It's plpgsql for Postgres, and that should work in a script, generally.